# What does `{x,y}<0` mean?

Tags: inequalities

```
In[1]:= Simplify[x<0, x<0]                                                      

Out[1]= True

In[2]:= Simplify[x<0, {x,y}<0]                                                  

Out[2]= x < 0

In[3]:= $Version                                                                

Out[3]= 11.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)
```

I always thought `{x,y}<0` meant the same thing as `{x<0, y<0}`, but, per `In[2]` above, this doesn't appear to be the case. Does `{x,y}<0` have a useful meaning or am I seeing a bug in Mathematica?

Comment: I've always understood `{x, y} < 0` to be nonsense.

Comment: `Simplify[x < 0, Thread[{x, y} < 0]]`

Comment: `Listable` inequalities are possible with `Positive`, `Negative`, etc.: `Simplify[x < 0, Negative[{x, y}]]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `Less` gives `True` or `False` when its arguments are real numbers.

Regardless of what `x` or `y` are, it is clear that `{x,y}` is not a real number, so `Less` doesn't do anything with it (for the most part, some simplifications may still be performed). Note that other functions may also treat `{x,y}<0` specifically, and that you can specifically define patterns that take advantage of this form. By itself though, `Less` is not listable, and does not expand in any way into the list. This is not a bug, just the nature of its definition.

As noted by Bob Hanlon in the comments, `Thread` can be used to turn `{x,y}<0` into `{x<0,y<0}` which is well-defined as a list of inequalities.

Answer (score 13):

Generally, this is an invalid use of `<`.  Both the left and the right-hand side should be expressions representing real numbers.

However, there are a few special cases where Mathematica will accept a list with `<`, `==`, `>`, such as

```
Solve[{x, y} < 2 && y == x^2]
(* {{y -> ConditionalExpression[x^2, -Sqrt[2] < x < Sqrt[2]]}} *)
```

This may have given you the impression that it is generally okay to use `<` this way. This is not the case though.

Comment: One can also use `Solve[{{x, y} < {1, 2}, y == x^2}]`, since `Solve` and `Reduce` apply `Thread` to (in)equalities that have a list as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

Writing something like `Simplify[x<0,x<0]` returns `True` because the second argument to `Simplify` is interpreted as an `Assumption` that is considered to be true.

Had the second argument been eg `x==1`, evaluating the preceding code segment would produce `False`; that result is not unexpected, since assuming that the value of `x` is equal to `1` (a positive number), the truth-value of `x<0` is expected to be `False`.

Now, when *Mathematica* evaluates `{x,y}<0`, it returns the same expression (provided that there are no other rules related to symbols `x` and `y`). This 
should not be surprising; it happens because `Less[List[x,y],0]` (which is the `FullForm` equivalent expression of `{x,y}<0`) is a valid *Wolfram Language* expression like eg `x>0`; evaluating `x>0` also returns `x>0` (again assuming no rules are attached to symbol `x` beforehand).

An expression like `{x,y}<0` might anticipate an evaluation result like `{x<0,y<0}`, but such an expectation is *not* warranted. The *function* (or 'operator') `Less` *does not* thread over its arguments (as has already been pointed out by other answers) much as some numeric functions like eg `Exp` or `Log` do.
Evaluating `Attributes[Exp]` or `Attributes[Log]` should return a list of the attributes attached to each symbol; in the case of eg `Log` it returns `{Listable, NumericFunction, Protected}`; the presence of `Listable` in the `Attributes` list of `Log` 'allows' the user to expect that eg `Log[{0,1}]` will evaluate to `{-Infinity, 0}`.

The evaluation of `{x,y}<0` does not return what's anticipated, because `Less` is not `Listable`.

What this means for the question at hand, is that when `Simplify` is presented with an `Assumption` that does not evaluate to a relevant relation (it simply reads `Less[List[x,y],0]`) for the expression it is expected to simplify-`x<0` in this case-it returns the best result it can deliver ie `x<0`, which-in this case-is the same expression it was presented with, in the first place.

This result is equivalent to eg `Simplify[x<0,y<0]`; again, in this case, too, the `Assumption` does not assist in simplifying the expression passed as a first argument to `Simplify`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an even more weird thing:

```
Reduce[{x,y}<0,{x,y}]
```

gives  `x<0 && y<0`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you believe this to be a weird result?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work if you set [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute for `Less` (`<`) first:

```
SetAttributes[Less, Listable]
Simplify[x < 0, {x, y} < 0]
(* True *)
```